# Kotlin LiveData list from Flow List

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I would like to know how do I make a LiveData list populated from a Flow list without having to create a separate model just for a list of the object.

User Data Class:

```
data class User(
    // object properties
)
```

Users Data Class:

```
data class UsersViewData(
    val users: List<User>
)
```

How I currently convert the Flow list to LiveData list in the ViewModel:

```
val users: LiveData<Users> = getUsers.users.map { users ->
        UsersViewData(users = users.map { it })
    }.asLiveData()
```

Is there a better way of doing this without having to create the UsersViewData data class?

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do. That says `LiveData<Users>` but you're creating it out of a `UsersViewData`. Did you mean to put `LiveData<UsersViewData>`? And we don't know what `getUsers` is. Is it a `Flow<UsersViewData>`? If so, why don't you simply use `getUsers.asLiveData()`?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thats's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by @Tenfour04 is:

```
val users: LiveData<List<UserViewData>> = getUsers.users.map { users ->
        users.map { it.toUserViewData() }
    }.asLiveData()
```